# Erro 500 ao tentar ler um PDF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Na view está assim:

```
<p:media cache="false" value="#{documents.readPDF()}" width="640px" height="480px" player="pdf" />
```

No bean está assim:

```
public StreamedContent readPDF() {
        FileModel pdfModel = getDocumentPDF();
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfModel.getBytes());
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", pdfModel.getFileName());
    }
```

Mas recebo um erro 500
http://localhost:8080/aerion/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml;/TestDocument%20of%20Web.pdf?ln=primefaces&v=6.1&pfdrid=fc3f2eba005bcd903c7eec3459182335&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=f3cf7c99-d4bf-4886-b3ea-d1b8bf07cf48

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, você postou uma URL local que não podemos abrir, se puder por gentileza apresente um print da tela com o erro.
Por gentilza também reveja as permissões do arquivo.

Não entendo muito bem de Java, mas tentei estruturar de outra forma o código, poderia testar?

Se eu tiver falando besteira, me desculpe.

```
public StreamedContent readPDF() {
        try {
        FileModel pdfModel = getDocumentPDF();
        InputStream stream;
        stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfModel.getBytes());
        StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, stream, "application/pdf", pdfModel.getFileName());
        return file;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
```